# A problem on continuous random variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

I was reading a The First course on Probability by Sheldon Ross, while I stuck at this possibly stupid doubt. 
The problem is :

> The density function of X is given by 
>   $$
> f(x) =
> \begin{cases}
> 2x,  & \text{if 0} \le x \le 1\\
> 0, & \text{otherwise}
> \end{cases}
> $$
>   Find $E[e^X]$.

**Solution**

> Let $Y = e^X $. We start by determining $F_Y$, the cumulative distribution function of Y. Now, for $1 \le x \le e$,
>   $$
> \begin{align}
> F_Y(x) & = P\{Y\le x\} \\
>  & = P\{e^X \le x\} \\ 
>  & = P\{X \le log(x)\} \\
>  & = \int _0^ {log(x)} \color{red}{f(y)dy}\\ 
>  & = log(x)
> \end{align}
> $$

The book further continues to taking derivative of $F_Y(x)$ to get the pdf of the $Y$ and to get the desired solution. What I didnt get is the text in red color: from where that $f(y)$ came?

I might be missing some stupid stuff here. Or there must be some gap in my logical understanding of the topic. Please help.

Comment: Big $F$ is the integral of little $f$, and $P\{X\leq\log(x)\}$ is big $F$

Comment: Yess but what about $y$? I felt its r.v. $X$, so it should be $f(x)dx$?

Comment: no $Y$ is $e^X$ not $X$.

Comment: But in $P\{X \le log(x)\}$ there is no $Y$ I was talking about $X$ in $P\{X \le log(x)\}$

Comment: Yes but since $Y=e^X$, the left hand side is $\log(Y)$.  But $\log(Y)=X$ so they just replaced $\log(Y)$ with $X$ there.  It's Kosher

Comment: Ah maybe what grdgfgr posted as an answer is what is bothering you?  That little $y$ in the integral has nothing to do with $Y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are being confused by the use of lower-case variables which **don't** correspond to the capital random-variables in the way you're anticipating.   The use of $F_Y(x)$ and $f_X(y)$, while legitimate, is counterintuitive.   They are 'dummy variables' and as such *any* token can be used; but *why* make a choice that is liable to confuse?   It's rather obtuse.

Does the calculus make more sense with different dummy variables?

$\begin{align}
F_Y(\color{blue}{t}) & = \mathsf P\{Y\le \color{blue}{t}\} 
\\[1ex]
 & = \mathsf P\{e^X \le \color{blue}{t}\} 
\\[1ex] 
 & = \mathsf P\{X \le \ln(\color{blue}{t})\} 
\\[1ex]
 & = \int_0^{\ln(\color{blue}{t})} f_X(\color{green}{s})\operatorname d\color{green}{s}
\\[1ex] 
 & = \int_0^{\ln(\color{blue}{t})} 2\color{green}{s}\operatorname d\color{green}{s}
\\[1ex] 
 & = \ln(\color{blue}{t})^2
\\[2ex]
f_Y(\color{blue}{t}) & = 2\frac{\ln(\color{blue}{t})}{\color{blue}{t}}
\\[2ex]
\mathbb E(Y) & = \int_{e^0}^{e^1} \color{blue}{t}f_Y(\color{blue}{t})\operatorname d\color{blue}{t}
\\ & = \int_{1}^{e} 2\ln(\color{blue}{t})\operatorname d\color{blue}{t}
\\ & = 2 \big(\color{blue}{t}\ln(\color{blue}{t})-\color{blue}{t}\big)\Big\rvert_{\color{blue}{t}=1}^{\color{blue}{t}=e}
\\ & = 2
\end{align}$

---

Meanwhile, this is an overly involved solution.   I suppose it demonstrates some principles, but really, you need just apply the definition of expectation.

$\begin{align}
f_X(x) & = 2x \cdot\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}
\\[2ex]
\mathbb E(e^X) & = \int_\Bbb R e^x\;f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] &= 2\int_0^1 x\;e^x\operatorname d x
\\[1ex] & = 2 e^x(x-1)\Bigr\rvert_{x=0}^{x=1}
\\[1ex] & = 2
\end{align}$

Answer (score 2):

y in the integral is a dummy variable. It could have been anything.

Comment: Yes.  Not to be confused with "a value of the random variable $Y$".  Maybe the calculation would have been better with something else, say $f(s)\;ds$.